# JQuery, keep inner <div> orginal position on animation of container <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a small website, and i'm having an issue with jQuery animation, 
Basically i have placed a small text (one character div) inside a circle (another div), and i want it to grow when the user hovers over it while keeping the inner div (text) at the original position, the circle will shrink back to original size upon mouseleave() event.
The growing/shrinking part is working quite good, the problem is with the inner text which changes position upon mouseenter().

Here's the HTML

```
 <body>
 <div class="steps">
    <div id="one" class="number">
        <div id="num-text">
            <p><strong>1</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

with 'steps' serving as a container and 'number' the actual circle !
Here's a link to the JSFiddle of this question: http://jsfiddle.net/Rockr90/hZSKA/

Thank you !

Edit:
Actually, the flickering only happens on Chrome, the example with CSS3 works on IE and FireFox as expected, maybe it has something to do with webkit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with CSS only! You dont need jQuery for this and I will explain how to do it with this example. I've used display table for the circle so that we can use display table-cell for perfectly centered text

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
    <p>1</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    position:relative; //set up a position, not needed, but for example
    top:100px;
    left:100px; // width and height
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:table; // display table for centered <p> with table-cell
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:50%; // make it a circle!
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; // transition
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.circle:hover {
    margin-left:-10px; // on hover we will increase the height and width
    margin-top:-10px; // we will also set the margin to - to make it stay on the same spot, +20 in height and width means -10 in margin
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}

.circle p {
    display:table-cell; // display table-cell magic
    vertical-align:middle; // put the text in the middle!
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    color:white;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/n6D46/

Comment: Only issue here is that it isn't very backwards compatible for old browsers (and all IE below 10!)

Comment: Silly me, didn't notice transition's speed on the CSS ! Thank you, i guess this will do, but I still prefer jQuery.

Comment: It seems nothing can be done for that flickering, It does work on IE10, and the irony ? there's no flickering on IE ... ??

Answer (score 1):

If you give `#num-text` a height, you can vertically align it to the center using the absolute positioning you already have on it:

```
#num-text {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    color:#eee;
    font-size:24px;
    width:100%;
    height: 24px;
    top:50%; margin-top:-12px; }
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hZSKA/1/

As a side note, it's probably possible to do this same effect using CSS3 but that may not be backwards compatible with older browsers.

Comment: Works great, thank you, however there's still some flickering around the '1' while the animation occurs, is there anyway to avoid this ?

Comment: Mmm yeh there is a bit of flickering. I also tried another solution where the jQuery animates the #num-text but that also flickered. You may need to consider changing the HTML structure slightly. Move the number out of it's parent divs and absolutely position everything.

Comment: In case you're interested, here the version using jQuery to position the number: http://jsfiddle.net/hZSKA/4/

Comment: I tried a version as you said, changing the HTML structure, and overlaying the '1' on the circle (using z-index), but there was a problem where hovering over '1' would halt the animation.

Answer (score 1):

A quick (but rough and tumble) fix would be to also animate `#num-text`:

```
     function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '-=10px',
            bottom: '-=5px',
            width: '-=10px'
        }, 50);
        $('#num-text').animate({'top': '-6px'}, 50)
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hZSKA/5/

Although I'm sure there will be better answers.

EDIT: whoops, linked to the wrong JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you, tried this one, but i want the '1' to stay as is, no movements.